# HTTP Request Not Getting Response

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send an HTTP request to of the form :

```
GET /api/content/v1/parser?url=http://blog.readability.com/2011/02/step-up-be-heard-readability-ideas/&token=1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e
```

The website I'm trying to communicate with is `www.readability.com`

I've been trying to use the following request:

```
string readabilityUrl = "http://www.readability.com";
string requestUrl = createRequestUrl(articleUrl);

// Create http request send to readability api
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(readabilityUrl + requestUrl);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(readabilityUrl);
var postData = requestUrl;
var postReqData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.Method = "POST";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postReqData, 0, postReqData.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
```

But all it does is getting the html content of `www.readaility.com` instead of returning the relevant data I actually need.

I guess I don't send the right parameters and I'd be thankful if you could help me out and point me to the solution.

Comment: You should use a debugging proxy (like Fiddler) to test fetching the URL.  Can you get it to work there first?

Comment: @David, first of all thanks for the answer. I've written a Python code which does exactly the same thing which works just fine. It seems like i need to create a conntection with readability.com and then send the request , am I right ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are getting HTML because you are being redirected from your target (HTTP 302). Check the content you are getting, maybe it contains an error about lacking credentials or that the resource does not exist.
2. Note you are creating a POST request, but the example you put at the beginning is a GET request.
3. You should encode the url you are using as parameter with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url)`